# What's the difference between fflib_SObjectDomain and fflib_SObjects?

Tags: apex, design-patterns, enterprise

We are implementing Apex Enterprise Design patterns in our org and I'm struggling to understand the difference between `fflib_SObjectDomain` and `fflib_SObjects`. There's very little documentation on the two. I've gone through Matt Gerry's excellent video tutorial "[The Complete Guide To The Apex Common Library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQrVEX4oE3A)" and he makes no distinction between these classes and references `fflib_SObjectDomain` but not `fflib_SObjects` in his video. I've also completed the related [Trailmix related to the Apex Common Library](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/users/bkbroughton/trailmixes/enterprise-patterns-library) and again, it doesn't mention the `fflib_SObjects` class at all.

I've studied the sample application implementing the Apex Common Library and this further adds to the confusion as the [Application class](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common-samplecode/blob/master/sfdx-source/apex-common-samplecode/main/classes/Application.cls) example maps classes of type `fflib_SObjects` whilst while defining the `DomainFactory` instead of mapping domain classes of type `fflib_SObjectDomain`.

```
public static final fflib_Application.DomainFactory Domain = 
    new fflib_Application.DomainFactory(
        Application.Selector,
        new Map<SObjectType, Type> {
                Opportunity.SObjectType => Opportunities.Constructor.class,
                OpportunityLineItem.SObjectType => OpportunityLineItems.Constructor.class,
                Account.SObjectType => Accounts.Constructor.class,
                DeveloperWorkItem__c.SObjectType => DeveloperWorkItems.class });
```

Further adding to the confusion, the sample application calls `fflib_SObjectDomain` classes [TriggerHandlers](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common-samplecode/blob/master/sfdx-source/apex-common-samplecode/main/classes/triggerHandlers/OpportunitiesTriggerHandler.cls) instead of Domain classes.

Finally, in opposition to the sample application, Matt Gerry's (Coding With The Force) example code maps `fflib_SObjectDomain` classes in [his Application class](https://github.com/Coding-With-The-Force/Salesforce-Separation-Of-Concerns-And-The-Apex-Common-Library/blob/main/src/classes/Apex_Common_Abstract_Task_Factory_Pattern_Example/Application.cls), instead of `fflib_SObjects` whilst defining the DomainFactory (see [Cases](https://github.com/Coding-With-The-Force/Salesforce-Separation-Of-Concerns-And-The-Apex-Common-Library/blob/main/src/classes/Apex_Common_Abstract_Task_Factory_Pattern_Example/Cases.cls) for example):

```
//This allows you to create a factory for instantiating domain classes. You can send it a set of record ids and
//you'll get the corresponding domain layer.
//Example initialization: fflib_ISObjectDomain objectDomain = Application.domain.newInstance(recordIds);
public static final fflib_Application.DomainFactory domain =
        new fflib_Application.DomainFactory(
                Application.selector,
                new Map<SObjectType, Type>{Case.SObjectType => Cases.Constructor.class,
                Contact.SObjectType => Contacts.Constructor.class,
                Account.SObjectType => Accounts.Constructor.class}
        );
```

So to pull this back around to my original question, what's the difference between `fflib_SObjectDomain` and `fflib_SObjects` and should I be mapping these `fflib_SObjects` clases in my DomainFactory or should I be mapping `fflib_SObjectDomain` classes in my DomainFactory?

Thank you.

Comment: My best guess is `fflib_SObjects` is a collections class wrapper of sorts but what makes me doubt this is that the sample application appears to map them as Domain classes whilst defining the `DomainFactory`.

Comment: this is covered by the author Wim Velzebor [here](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/pull/300) and [here](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/pull/273).  The documentation in books like Lightning Platform Enterprise Architecture hasn't caught up to this change.  You can engage Wim directly in Github apex-common library

Comment: also, check out this comment (by me) [here](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/discussions/323#discussioncomment-4586926). I'll admit, I haven't converted my legacy code base to the new structure but the principles are good :triggerHandlers are triggerHandlers and domains are domains rather than being domains+ triggerHandlers

Comment: @cropredy you should turn these comments into an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation in books like Lightning Platform Enterprise Architecture hasn't caught up to this change

Here's a summary (I'll use `Opportunity` as the example)

**Books/videos/trailhead/etc**

- Domain class named `Opportunities`:

  - Extended `fflib_SObjectDomain`
  - Trigger handler for all DML events on `Opportunity`
  - Optional other methods that could be performed on lists of `Opportunity` SObjects
  - mockable via ApexMocks for Unit Testing

The domain class is essentially a wrapper around a collection of SObjects of a given type - allowing one to perform operations on the collection where the primary use case is handling trigger events but other use cases are easily imaginable.

**Latest fflib**

The prior domain class `Opportunities` becomes *two classes*

- `OpportunityTriggerHandler` - extends `fflib_SObjectDomain`

  - Only serves to perform trigger handling
  - Constructed only by `fflib_SObjectDomain.triggerHandler(OpportunityTriggerHandler.class`)
  - No `newInstance` method; not constructed by Application factories
- `Opportunities` extends `fflib_SObjects`

  - Does not do trigger handling
  - Intended to do domain-y stuff on collections of SObjects
  - Can be constructed using the Application Domain factory and hence implicitly supports mock domains using ApexMocks `setMock()`

Class hierarchy

```
 fflib_SobjectDomain extends fflib_SObjects extends fflib_Objects
```

You can see this in the [apex-common-samplecode github repo](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common-samplecode/tree/master/sfdx-source/apex-common-samplecode/main) by inspecting:

- `Application.cls`
- `OpportunityTriggerHandler.cls`
- `Opportunities.cls`
- `OpportunitiesTrigger.trigger`

One possible point of confusion is the `XxxTriggerHandler` extending `fflib_SObjectDomain` when the trigger handler is not the domain class any more. I believe, reading through all the PR comments, that this was done for backward compatibility reasons so existing code bases could be upgraded.  This allows legacy code bases to retain the dual function domain+triggerHandler logic in a single class and as one adds new triggers, one can adopt the new two-class model (one for triggerHandler, one for domain)

The PR author, Wim Velzebor, makes reference to how one can also construct domains of arbitrary ApexTypes. Such domains would extend `fflib_Objects`. There is no Application factory support in the sample code for such domains of ApexTypes but one could imagine this.

Comment: Excellent breakdown. Thanks for all your help.